# Python Queue - Why Is It Getting Still Growing?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I have a server taking TCP data and spawning threads to parse up and deal with the data. I noticed if it starts to get too many connections something goes wrong and it starts grinding to a halt so after hunting around I discovered that my queue steadily gets more and more data even though I'm constantly using a q.get().

Snippet of the Queue emptying thread:

```
def QDUmp():
    while 1:
        if not q.empty():

            data= str(q.get())
            ParseThread = Thread(target = ParseFunction(data))
            ParseThread.start()

CheckQ = Thread(target = QDUmp)
CheckQ.start()
```

The data is constantly being added by the TCP just with a standart put like this pseudo:

```
q = Queue.Queue()

For eachdata from Socket:
  q.put(eachdata)
```

So... data comes in and data goes out but it's not going out quick enough.

The longer it runs the more and more data is sitting in that q. As I understood it q.get() would of removed the data from there and for every bit of data there it should be spawning a thread to remove it.

Can anyone shed some light on how I'm winding up with more and more data in that queue?

Is it just coming in faster than while 1: is able to loop around and check it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the TCP data receiver is too fast than your data processor. You can add a counter to count how many data in and how many data out, so you can know whether the queue is growing continuously.

Comment: It certainly takes longer to parse the data than it does to receive it but if I'm just spawning threads for every bit of data that comes in is there some limit to the number of threads I'm able to spawn? (It's running on Windows) there's no ,join() for the threads so I'd just expected it to keep spawning threads as the data came in.